# Word for a word that changes spelling but not meaning?

Tags: orthography

What is the word that describes a word that has changed in spelling but not meaning, such as how the word "to-day" was once spelt "today"?

Comment: I think you mean *... such as how the word "today" was once spelt "to-day"*. [Nobody hyphenates it today](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to-day%2Ctoday&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20-%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoday%3B%2Cc0) (and [hardly anyone still writes "spelt"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spelled%2Cspelt&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspelled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspelt%3B%2Cc0) either! :)

Comment: Nobody is an exaggeration. Bossman spelt it with a hyphen to-day ;)

Comment: Forsooth, but methinks thy mother tongue hath simply evolved.

Comment: And spelt is standard British usage.  Plus, a type of wheat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single word for this is **variant**.  More completely variant spelling.

> **variant spelling**
>
> noun
>
> A different spelling for a single word. Typically a US vs. UK or US vs. Commonwealth distinction.

For example, *color* and *colour* are the same word [spelt](http://grammarist.com/spelling/spelled-spelt/) in the American and British styles respectively.  You'd think there'd be a word for this that fits into this system:

> **homograph**
>
> Use the noun homograph to talk about two words that are spelled the same but have different meanings and are pronounced differently — like "sow," meaning female pig, and "sow," to plant seeds.
>   Continue reading...
>
> **homonym**
>
> A homonym is a word that is said or spelled the same way as another word but has a different meaning. "Write” and “right” is a good example of a pair of homonyms.
>   Continue reading...
>
> **homophone**
>
> A homophone is a word that sounds the same as another word but has a different meaning and/or spelling. “Flower” and “flour” are homophones because they are pronounced the same but you certainly can’t bake a cake using daffodils.
>
> [vocabulary.com: homonym-homophone-homograph](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/homonym-homophone-homograph/)

The hetero prefix is the counterpoint to homo prefix used here.  Hetero means different where homo means the same.  So one might imagine **hetrograph** is the word you want.  However:

> Heterographs are words that sound the same as other words, but they have different spellings and different meanings. For the English language learner or for young students, these words can be very confusing.
>
> [google: heterograph definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=heterograph%20definition)

So heterograph doesn't work if you want this exact meaning.  There is [a very similar question on linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/same-meaning-same-pronunciation-different-spelling) that illustrates the distinctions with a Venn diagram.

[image]

This originally comes from the [wikipedia article on Homonym's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) which has a very easy to read table:

[image]

that is clearly missing your meaning:

```
      Term       | Meaning | Spelling  | Pronunciation
-----------------+---------+-----------+--------------
Variant spelling | Same    | Different | Same
```