# What is the term for a word with two quite different spellings that are pronounced alike?

Tags: meaning, orthography

If you are willing to go back aways, many words have alternative spellings with the same pronunciation. Take the fishy spelling of *The Compleat Angler,* for example.  But some modern words have two current dramatically different spellings pronounced alike. One example is the spellings of **controller** and **comptroller**. In *The Way We Live Now,* Anthony Trollope has one character say **vittles** and another say **victuals.** Note that these are not homonyms because only one word is being spelled.

In saying "two quite different spellings," I am trying to eliminate spelling variants such as today vs. to-day, colour vs. color, or the example I gave, complete vs. compleat. In such pairs, everyone would naturally pronounce the two spellings alike. That's not the case with vittles vs. victuals, hiccup vs. hiccough, or controller vs. comptroller. Indeed, some people (not I) do not pronounce the last pair alike. So I do not believe that my question is in the same spirit as a previous question. Though there is a distinction to be made, it may be that English has no word for this distinction, and all that can be said is that the words I'm considering have extreme spelling variants.

Comment: I think they are homophones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for a word that changes spelling but not meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317759/word-for-a-word-that-changes-spelling-but-not-meaning)

Comment: @Josh The OP's title and your comment mislead me, I've retracted the close vote. Apologies.

Comment: @Drew - it is not the same question.

Comment: @Josh I was going to comment the same, but when I checked the definition of _homophone_, it was "words with different meanings". I still have doubts whether comptrollor and controller are the same thing, and the others are just alternate or variant spellings, or dialect.

Comment: Call them **spelling variants**

Comment: http://www.magickeys.com/books/riddles/words.html

Comment: @NVZ I was hoping for something like "heterograph," but I guess it's knot too bee.

Comment: Uh, could you give some more examples of the words that are pronounced the same??  The only one I see is "compleat" (vs, I presume, "complete"), and that's simply an archaic spelling.

Comment: Nought comes to mind at the moment.

Comment: @Hot Licks While I'm on the subject of nothing, i.e. naught and nought, in Shakespeare's day "nothing" and "noting" were nearly homonyms, which explains the pun in his title, "Much Ado about Nothing." Indeed "compleat" is an archaic spelling of complete, but Walton used it to mean complete in the sense of accomplished or consummate.

Comment: @ Hot Licks THe only thing I can think of topping "catsup" and "ketchup"  is "hiccup" and " hicough."

Comment: I dunno anyone who pronounces *comptroller* the same as *controller*. Anyway, the OED lists *comptroller* as a *variant* or *alteration* of another *lexical item*, namely *controller*. In this case it is taken as both a variant and as a probable deliberate alteration of *controller*. So they could be called variant lexical items; it does seem simpler to just say *variant* spellings.

Comment: I like **gaol** and **jail**, especially good for Scrabble players.

Comment: I was taught that 'victuals' _is_ pronounced 'vittles'. If Trollope used both spellings, the second is probably an example of the old-fashioned convention of spelling words phonetically to suggest uneducated speech.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Yes that's exactly how Trollope used "vittles." I think "vittles" is accepted English in the US. At least it still used in the South. Here is Merriam Webster's example:"claimed that the chitlins were just about the tastiest vittles he ever ate." Of course "chitlins" is a whole 'nother can of worms.

Answer (score 2):

"[A] word that has the same pronunciation as one or more other words but has different spelling or meaning" is a [homophone](http://www.homophones.ml).

Source:
[www.homophones.ml](http://www.homophones.ml)

Answer (score 0):

In your question you specify that they're pronounced the same, and then specify that they are NOT pronounced the same, so I'm unsure which you mean.

Spelled differently **and** pronounced differently?  Those are simply synonyms.  Spelling variations on essentially the same word (different spelling, but same pronunciation and definition) would be alternate spellings, not unlike color/colour.

Answer (score 0):

There are inherently two forces in action:

the phenomenon of etymological doublets and differences in phono-orthographic spellings due either to a social or inter-linguistic transliteration. 
Concerning the first, consider the doublets, 'emergence' and 'emergency'. The two have a transparent etymology dating to the Latin etymon 'emergere' - to give light to/appear. The meaning, and understanding, of the two words grew to differ perhaps on pragmatic grounds: one derivate of 'emergentia' denoted an exigent matter coming to light while the converse denoted appearance of a certain property.

I believe in the exemplar you raised regarding comptroller and controller, they inherently emerge from the same Latin root. The demarcation arises when one considers 'comptroller' a portmanteau of the French verb 'compter', to count and 'controlere', to control. These are not homonyms, for this phrase implies that the two have the same orthography but differing meanings, nor homophones, due to the feasibly distinct phonologies of the respective words from an intermediate  language.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this could be considered a cognate within the same language. Your controller/comptroller example makes it even more interesting, as it then becomes a cognate within the same language, but of two different national dialects.

Comment: Not sure this is correct. *Cognates* by definition seem to be words that are related _based on language derivation_, not words that are _spelled differently but pronounced alike_, which is what the questioner is discussing.

Comment: @Stephen I have not made myself clear. I am talking about one word with spellings so different that a non-English speaker might be surprised to find that they have essentially the same pronunciation. GEdgar's  gaol and jail is a good example. I admit that ketchup and catsup have slightly different pronunciations and that while controller and comptroller are pronounced the same by some like me, there is an alternative pronunciation of comptroller that is different.  I'm sorry if these two examples were confusing, but the idea is one word, one pronunciation and two quite different spellings.